# Am I Seeding the Data Correctly or Doing Something Else Wrong?

Tags: c#, html, .net, database, configuration

I am trying to display the value of an object that is within another object. I have been rewriting this for days and googled it to death trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. I started with a much more complex project, but now I've written a very simple school one to use as an example and to try different things with.  I've rewritten the configuration at least 30 different ways based on examples from the internet and nothing has worked so far. Any help at getting me unstuck would be very much appreciated!

Classes:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int teacherID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    public int? teacherID { get; set; }
    public Teacher teacher { get; set; }
}

public class schoolDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
protected override void Seed(school.Models.schoolDBContext context)
        {

        context.Courses.AddOrUpdate(i => i.ID,
            new Course
            {
                courseName = "Math",
                teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 1, name = "Ms. Brooks" },
                teacherID = 1
            },
             new Course
            {
                courseName = "Science",
                teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 2, name = "Ms. James" },
                teacherID = 2
            },
            new Course
            {
                courseName = "History",
                teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 3, name = "Ms. Davidson"},
                teacherID = 3
            }
       );
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<school.Models.Course>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.courseName)
        </th>
        <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.teacher.name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.teacher.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

[image: What the view looks like]

How do I get the teacher's name to display in the course view?

If I do this in the controller, everything works just fine.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var _coursesList = new List<Course>();
        _coursesList.Add(new Course { ID = 1, courseName = "English", teacherID = 1, teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 1, name = "Mrs. Thomas" } });
        _coursesList.Add(new Course { ID = 2, courseName = "History", teacherID = 2, teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 2, name = "Ms. Jones" } });
        _coursesList.Add(new Course { ID = 3, courseName = "Math", teacherID = 2, teacher = new Teacher { teacherID = 2, name = "Ms. Fisher" } });

        return View(_coursesList);

       // return View(db.Courses.ToList());
    }
```

[image: Code Working]

So it must be the way that I am seeding the data that is the problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.teacher.name)
    </td>
```

In the lambda:

```
DisplayFor(modelItem => item.teacher.name)
```

It looks like you are pulling off the wrong item.

Although, based on how you have created your iteration, why aren't you using:

```
@item.teacher.name
```

instead of:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.teacher.name)
```

Comment: I want the name of the teacher that has been assigned to the course by getting the information from the course. How else would you write it other than item.teacher.name for the course? Also, when I create them in the controller and return them that way, they appear correctly, so I don't think that it is the HTML that is the problem.  I don't understand the second part of your answer where you ask why I don't use @item.teacher.name instead of @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseName), those are two different things that I am trying to display.

Comment: @Amanda Sorry about that, edited. The lambda itself is looking at different things. in `modelItem => item.teacher.name` the lambda is cast and operating on modelItem. item is an external object that is being operated on in this case

Comment: I get a null reference exception when I change it to @item.teacher.name